# import error when we run robot file via bat script for the robot project with java (jython)

Tags: batch-file, jenkins, robotframework, python-import, jython

We have created robot framework with java using Jython as below.

[image: Project structure]

When we execute this from Eclipse IDE and it works fine.

We are going to configure this into Jenkins and we have created the below batch script for
Build and test

Build:

```
call mvn clean
call mvn assembly:assembly -DdescriptorId=jar-with-dependencies
build is created successfully
```

Test:

```
java -cp target\KTOC-TRB-automation-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar;robotframework-3.0.2.jar -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=chromedrivers\chromedriver.exe -Dheadless=false org.robotframework.RobotFramework --variablefile KTOC_TRB_TestAutomation\FrontlinesTRB\France.py --variablefile KTOC_TRB_TestAutomation\FrontlinesTRB\TRB-env.py KTOC_TRB_TestAutomation\TestSuites\RegressionTest_France.robot
```

When we trigger this script, we are getting the below error :

> ```
> C:\Users\k64066262\rep\KTOC-TRB-Automation>test.bat >>status.txt
> [ ERROR ] Error in file 'C:\Users\k64066262\rep\KTOC-TRB-Automation\KTOC_TRB_TestAutomation\TestSuites\RegressionTest_France.robot': Importing test library 'com.KTOC.TRB.testautomation.Keywords.Keywords' failed: ImportError: No module named KTOC
> ```

[image: Error message]

error message :

> ```
> C:\Users\k64066262\rep\KTOC-TRB-Automation>java -cp target\KTOC-TRB-automation-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar;robotframework-3.0.2.jar -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=chromedrivers\chromedriver.exe -Dheadless=false org.robotframework.RobotFramework --variablefile KTOC_TRB_TestAutomation\FrontlinesTRB\France.py --variablefile KTOC_TRB_TestAutomation\FrontlinesTRB\TRB-env.py KTOC_TRB_TestAutomation\TestSuites\RegressionTest_France.robot 
> ==============================================================================
> RegressionTest France                                                         
> ==============================================================================
> Verify Tender Created Successfully                                    | FAIL |
> Parent suite setup failed:
> No keyword with name 'Launch Browser' found.
> ```

Comment: _"No module named KTOC"_?

Comment: @GerhardBarnard yes.. KTOC we mentioned in the keywords folder name.. as you can see in above project struture. we dont have any module name as KTOC. It should check Launch Browser keyword in Keywords.java file and it should exeucte but it didnt